Form.io hide Component tabs like API, Conditional, Logic and Layout tabs
I am working on the form.io from builder integration part. I am not able to hide API, Conditional, Logic and Layout Tabs.
I am using angular JS version 1. Here i have added default configuration for that.
I am not able to hide that. How can i do that?
I also want to hide the help section.

Code Snippet:-
     var builderOptions = {
  builder: {
    allComponents: {
      title: 'Components',
      weight: 0,
      default: true,
      components: {
        textfield: true,
        textarea: true,
        number: true,
        mycomponent: true, // Example custom component
      },
    },
    // Disable other groups
    basic: false,
    advanced: false,
    layout: false,
    data: false,
    premium: false,
  },

};

Formio.builder(document.getElementById('builder'), {}, builderOptions)
  .then(function(builder) {
  console.log(formioComponents);
  console.log(builder);
  builder.on('change', function(schema) {
    console.log('Form Schema Changed:', schema);
    $scope.formSchema = schema;
    $scope.$apply();
  });
});


